# Each login creates a new StackExchange account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, linked-accounts, merge-accounts

I have a user on SharePoint StackExchange with some reputation. On this computer I am logged in and can work with this account.

If I use another browser or another computer, of course I am not logged in.
When I try to log in by entering my mail adress and password, StackExchange want to create a new account.

[image]

After confirm I get a **new** account SharePoint StackExchange account with no reputation and I cannot "work" on my given answers.

*It's like Facebook would give me a new account with an empty friendlist on each login on a new device.*

I have to **contact support to merge** the new created account with my existing account.

I understand the princip of having different user profiles for different StackExchange Q+A pages. But I don't understand why I always get a new account on a simple login.

Why does this happen?
Did I do something wrong or should I login with G+ or Facebook to prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

By using Google+, Facebook or some other 3<sup>rd</sup> party OpenID provider you will definitely avoid this problem as Stack Exchange will recognise you the next time you are logged on.

You can add additional logins to your account from your profile page. Do this from the computer where you initially logged in.

However, I thought that logging in via an email address and password created a Stack Exchange OpenID which should be the same as using a 3<sup>rd</sup> party one.

Comment: I connected my account with Facebook. Under "My Logins" I have now two entries (StackExchange and Facebook Acoount). But when I try to login with my Facebook account on another computer, it also want to create a new account. I don't get it...