# Two Stack Exchange Open ID

Tags: discussion, bug, login, stack-exchange-openid

The post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246849/278826) seem to suggest that it's possible to create 2 separate accounts using the same username and password. Is it a bug? Or is it supposed to work like this? Should it not ask the user to provide a new user ID as the one he's trying to create has an account linked to it?

Edit 1: 
This is not a duplicate because the post I linked asked for a solution for the problem.

1. I am asking why it was allowed in the first place.
2. I am asking about how the login engine works?
3. How is it possible to have two exactly same user ID?